# Website URI formats are not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web

From the other answers I read, I have no idea what anyone is talking about. I am making a website in HTML/JavaScript. No ASP code or C# code exists that I am aware of, so I cant implement any solutions other answers are talking about.

Since I dont use those languages, is it even possible to use the Class Diagram for HTML/JavaScript objects?

Error message I get when I try to view the Class Diagram:

```
   Cannot load 'C:\Google
   Drive\Projects\Web\WestSlopeRecovery\www\App_Code\Class
   Diagram.cd': URI formats are not supported.
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about, and it's not clear to me that you do, either.

Comment: can I view the Class Diagram for HTML/JavaScript objects? I dont know how to fix that error when I dont code in ASP or C#

Comment: Yeah, Im new to this stuff, so I am not sure what to ask. Trying to get Class Diagram to work with HTML/JavaScript code on the website.

Comment: Class diagrams in Visual Studio don't work for HTML or JavaScript files. Only C# or VB.NET or other .NET types.

Comment: Thanks. Thats useful to know. That pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Class diagrams in Visual Studio don't work for HTML or JavaScript files. Only C# or VB.NET or other .NET types.
–John Saunders

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer. You may want to delete yours.

Answer (score 0):

Class diagrams in Visual Studio don't work for HTML or JavaScript files. Only C# or VB.NET or other .NET types.